# Can someone explain Xamarin padding order?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've looked through the Xamarin help pages, and might have missed something. As I cannot seem to find any explanation of what the padding numbers are. Here for example:

```
<StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0">
<StackLayout Padding="20,10,0,0">
<StackLayout Padding="20,0">
```

What is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th and what happens when I just specify two padding numbers?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

They're defined as a [Thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Thickness)

1 parameter - uniform size

2 parameters - horizontal, vertical

4 parameters - left, top, right, bottom

Comment: This is so confusing, because I had mine as Padding="20 0 0 0" (without commas) and 20 was the top padding (and this works in the previewer!), whereas with commas the second item is the top padding.